# how do i do binary search tree rotation in java?

Tags: java, recursion, rotation, binary-search-tree

SO I am writing a code for a project where I am to rotate a node to the left and rotate it to the right, I have it written out but when I run it two things occur, my rotate left method is rotating to the right rather than left, I've tried changing things around it still rotates to the right, as for my rotate right i get the null pointer exception when i try to run it. I can only use one return statement per method and has to be done recursively here are the two methods, I am in desperate need of help!!

```
   public void rotateLeft(int num) {
      root=rotateLeft(root,num);


    }
    private static IntNode rotateLeft(IntNode T,int num){

      //easiest case
      if(T==null)
      {
      }
        //rotation part       
      else if(num==T.getNum())
      {
         IntNode oldRight=T.getRight();
         if(T.getRight()!=null){
          T.setRight(oldRight.getLeft());
         oldRight.setLeft(T);
         T=oldRight;
         }
         else {
         }
      }
       else if(num>T.getNum())
      {
         T.setRight(rotateLeft(T.getRight(),num));
      }
      //recursion
      else
      {
         T.setLeft(rotateLeft(T.getLeft(),num));
}


      return  T;




         }
  // Rotate the node containing num to the right -- do nothing if not possible
    public void rotateRight(int num) {
      root=rotateRight(root,num);
    }
    private static IntNode rotateRight(IntNode T,int num)
    {
      IntNode oldLeft=T.getLeft();

      //easiest case
      if(T==null)
      {

      }
      //rotation part
        else if(num==T.getNum())
      {
         if(T.getLeft()!=null){
          T.setLeft(oldLeft.getLeft());
         oldLeft.setRight(T);
         T=oldLeft;
         }
         else {
         }
      }
       else if(num>T.getNum())
      {
         T.setLeft(rotateRight(T.getLeft(),num));
      }
      else
      {
         T.setRight(rotateRight(T.getRight(),num));
}






     return T;

    }
```

Comment: What will happen if `rotateRight()` is called and `T` is `null`?

Comment: i managed to fix my rotate right method its just my left that im having trouble with, if T is null then I dont want the method to do anything @ChuckB